# How to follow a list of links to get data from pages in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a web page to scrape.  On the page, is a list of links in a `<table>`.  I'm trying to use the rules section to ask Scrapy to go through the links, and get data on the pages the links target.  Below is my code:

```
class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'coinmarketcap'
    start_urls = [
        'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//tr/td[2]/a/@href',)), callback="parse", follow= True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        print("TEST TEST TEST")
        BTC = BTCItem()
        BTC['source'] = str(response.request.url).split("/")[2]
        BTC['asset'] = str(response.request.url).split("/")[4],
        BTC['asset_price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="quote_price"]/text()').extract(),
        BTC['asset_price_change'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]/text()').extract(),
        BTC['BTC_price'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/small[1]/text()').extract(),
        BTC['Prct_change'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/small[2]/text()').extract()
        yield (BTC)
```

My problem is that Scrapy is not following the links. It just takes the link at attempts to extract data from that link.  What am I missing?

UPDATE #1:
Why crawl vs scrape?

```
2017-03-28 23:10:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/pivx/> (referer: None)
2017-03-28 23:10:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/zcash/> (referer: None)
2017-03-28 23:10:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/> (referer: None)
2017-03-28 23:10:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/nem/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit from a [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) class for the link extractor to work:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'coinmarketcap'
    start_urls = [
        'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//tr/td[2]/a'), callback="parse_table_links", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_table_links(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Note that you need to fix the `restrict_xpaths` value - it should point to an `a` element and not the `@href` attribute of an element. And, you may define it as a string instead of a tuple.

Also, the `allow` argument is optional.

Comment: sorry to ask afterwards, but if you look at update#1, it crawls some pages, scrapes others.  can you tell me why?

Comment: I'm looking to scrape ALL pages it goes to

Comment: @arcee123 I think you should get all of them - please recheck the console output - you should see both "crawled" and "scraped from" log messages for every url. Thanks.

Comment: ok.  I'm not.  there's over 670 links to pass through, it's not getting all of them.  the source is here: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/

Comment: @arcee123 wait, I've just dumped all the results into a json file and got 890 links there. Could you please elaborate the problem, if it is still reproducible, in a separate question? This way, more people can potentially help and, there is a possibility you'll see the problem while describing it :) Thanks.

Comment: tell you what.  to give you more credit, I'll open another question.

Comment: I put it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084632/scrapy-crawler-only-pulls-19-of-680-urls.  Thanks again.