# Scrapy Crawler only pulls 19 of 680+ urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape this page:  https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/

in `td[2]` of all the rows is a link.  I am trying to ask scrapy to go to each link in that `td`, and scrape pages that link represents.  Below is my code:

**note: another person was awesome in helping me get this far**

```
class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'coinmarketcap'
    start_urls = [
        'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//td[2]/a',)), callback="parse", follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        BTC = BTCItem()
        BTC['source'] = str(response.request.url).split("/")[2]
        BTC['asset'] = str(response.request.url).split("/")[4],
        BTC['asset_price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="quote_price"]/text()').extract(),
        BTC['asset_price_change'] = response.xpath(
            '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]/text()').extract(),
        BTC['BTC_price'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/small[1]/text()').extract(),
        BTC['Prct_change'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/small[2]/text()').extract()
        yield (BTC)
```

even tho the table exceeds 600+ links/pages, when I run `scrapy crawl coinmarketcap`, I only get 19 records.  This means only 19 pages from this list of 600+.  I'm failing to see the issue stopping the scrape.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please share you crawl logs, especially the stats dict at the end, where you can see the number of requests that were scheduled, how many were filtered perhaps, the various status codes you got etc.

Comment: What if you change the callback from `parse()` to, say, `parse_item()` (and adjust the callback name in the rule too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spider goes too deep: with that rule it find and follow links also in the single coin's pages. You can roughly fix the problem adding a DEPTH_LIMIT = 1, but you can for sure find a more elegant solution.
Here the code that works for me (there are other minor adjustment too):

```
class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'coinmarketcap'
    start_urls = [
        'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/'
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': '1',
    }

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//td[2]',)),callback="parse_item", follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        BTC = BTCItem()
        BTC['source'] = str(response.request.url).split("/")[2]
        BTC['asset'] = str(response.request.url).split("/")[4]
        BTC['asset_price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="quote_price"]/text()').extract()
        BTC['asset_price_change'] = response.xpath(
            '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        BTC['BTC_price'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/small[1]/text()').extract()
        BTC['Prct_change'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/small[2]/text()').extract()
        yield (BTC)
```

Comment: you sir are awesome!!!! it works!.  Tell me, besides the Depth_limit, what else did you change?

Comment: As suggested by alecxe I  changed the callback from parse() to parse_item() and I removed some unnecessary commas.